# Getting flutter project to call kotlin code without flutter create -a kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, dart, flutter

I created a flutter project without the command `flutter create -a kotlin`. I want to add the ability to use kotlin code back into the project.

I have tried creating a kotlin path directory down, but that doesn't work. When running the code, all I get is the following:

```
03-15 23:01:40.490 3914-3914/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: lawonga.divly, PID: 3914
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{lawonga.divly/lawonga.divly.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "lawonga.divly.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/lawonga.divly-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/lawonga.divly-1/lib/x86_64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
```

I have the methods channels set up properly.

I also took a look at the sample `platformchannel` app, and translated the `MainActivity` there into kotlin code and put it into the directory `kotlin.com.example.platformchannel.MainActivity`, but it seems to be trying to read off of the java package still.

Does anyone know how to get Flutter to read Kotlin code?

Comment: You might have to update the `AndroidManifest.xml` to point to your new `MainActivity`.

Comment: I figured it out - will post answer shortly

Comment: I have a similar issue. Can you post your answer please?

Comment: Oh yeah, you basically will didn't move the files to the correct location.

Comment: Double check your directories, they might have the incorrect path/names